# 2d bin packing using or-tools: AddNoOverlap2D and OnlyEnforceIf gives MODEL_INVALID

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I am playing with a 2d bin packing model. I tried this using:

```
for j in range(n):
  for i in range(j):
    model.Add(b[i] == b[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)])  # not needed?
    model.Add(b[i] != b[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)].Not())
    model.AddNoOverlap2D([xival[i],xival[j]],[yival[i],yival[j]]).OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)])
```

The purpose here is to only enforce the no-overlap constraint if items i and j are assigned to the same bin. The combination of `AddNoOverlap2D` and `OnlyEnforceIf` seems to give the status:

```
MODEL_INVALID
```

If I remove `OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)])` the (now incorrect) model solves fine.

Am I correct to conclude this is just not supported in or-tools (yet)?

I guess I can reformulate things to more MIP-like approach.

A reproducible example is below. I used version 8.1.8487.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

#---------------------------------------------------
# data 
#---------------------------------------------------


# bin width and height
H = 60
W = 40

# h,w for each item
h = [7,7]
w = [12,12]
n = len(h)  # number of items
m = 2      # number of bins

#---------------------------------------------------
# or-tools model 
#---------------------------------------------------


model = cp_model.CpModel()

#
# variables
#

# x1,x2 and y1,y2 are start and end
x1 = [model.NewIntVar(0,W-w[i],'x1{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]
x2 = [model.NewIntVar(w[i],W,'x2{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]

y1 = [model.NewIntVar(0,H-h[i],'y1{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]
y2 = [model.NewIntVar(h[i],H,'y2{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]

# interval variables
xival = [model.NewIntervalVar(x1[i],w[i],x2[i],'xival{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]
yival = [model.NewIntervalVar(y1[i],w[i],y2[i],'yival{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]

# bin numbers
b = [model.NewIntVar(0,m-1,'b{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]

# b2[(i,j)] = true if b[i]=b[j] for i<j
b2 = {(i,j):model.NewBoolVar('b2{}.{}'.format(i,j)) for j in range(n) for i in range(j)}

#
# constraints
#

for j in range(n):
  for i in range(j):
    model.Add(b[i] == b[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)])  # not needed?
    model.Add(b[i] != b[j]).OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)].Not())
    model.AddNoOverlap2D([xival[i],xival[j]],[yival[i],yival[j]]).OnlyEnforceIf(b2[(i,j)])
#    model.AddNoOverlap2D([xival[i],xival[j]],[yival[i],yival[j]])  # this one works


#
# solve model
#
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
rc = solver.Solve(model)
print(rc)
print(solver.StatusName())
```

Notes:

- As indicated in the answer, this is just not supported.
- A different formulation for this 2d bin packing problem is shown [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/02/2d-bin-packing-with-google-or-tools-cp.html). That seems to work quite well.
- It is further noted that the pairwise **NoOverlap2D** formulation may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True` you'll see:

```
Parameters: log_search_progress: true
Enforcement literal not supported in constraint: enforcement_literal: 11 no_overlap_2d { x_intervals: 0 x_intervals: 1 y_intervals: 2 y_intervals: 3 }
...
```

So yeah, it isn't supported, maybe you can open a feature request as documented [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/cp_model.proto#L268).

But I think you can also solve it using `OptionalIntervalVar` if you encode the bin number with booleans.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see immediately how I can use `OptionalIntervalVar` in this context. (that is about a single item, while "i,j in the same bin" is about two items).

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of one OptionalIntervalVar per (item, bin) as the noOverlap will ignore the inactive ones, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Got it. Worth trying out.

Comment: If it does work out feel free to self-answer the question yourself and accept it instead.